# IF formula with IP in excel

Tags: excel

Column B
192.168.0.1

and in column C:

```
=IF(len(b1)>0,IF(b1="192.168.0.10","Nothing needed","Should Change"),"")
```

this formula doesn't work, after I hit enter on c1, the formula changed to (192.168010)

I just want to see column B has this IP address 192.168.0.10 or not.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Excel 2010? version please

Comment: Excel Version is 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that "192.168.0.1" <> "192.168.0.10" in a string comparison.

When I make the correction (in EXCEL 2010) it works fine for me.

[image]

Comment: ha :-), I open new sheet and try it, it's work at there, but doesn't work in my sheet.

Comment: That was extera space, fix the issue with Trim.